# Delete comment link not working (acts_as_commentable)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, each post has a comment section where users can leave comments. I want each comment to have a delete link but I just can't get it to work. I am using the acts_as_commentable gem here.

posts/show.html.erb

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p><strong><%= comment.user.username %></strong></p>
  <p class="comment"><%= comment.comment %><p>
  <%= link_to "Delete", [@post, comment], method: :delete %> 
<% end %>
```

I need help with this line

```
<%= link_to("Delete", [@post, comment], method: :delete %>
```

comments_controller.rb

```
def create 
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]) 
  @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params) 
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id 
end

def destroy
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: can you tell me which error you get when you try to delete comment ?

Comment: Hey, I don't get any error at all. The page will refresh when the delete link is clicked but the comment doesn't get deleted.

Comment: Please paste you server log here

Comment: @Joshua You can check the log in server .  try to write exit in destroy method than you can trace you code there..

Comment: @Joshua that's what you have written in your controller. Redirect to back on click. Where you have written to delete comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not destroying it at all in the `destroy` action, you need to add `@comment.destroy` to delete the comment from database

```
def destroy
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id]
  @comment.destroy # add this line
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

change destroy action something like this:

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to :back
end
```

In this way you can make sure you are deleting comment related to specific post. It's rails proffered way you can look at it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-comments) .

Comment: Or in a single query, `comment = Comment.find_by(id: params[:id], post_id: params[:post_id])`